# How to interpolate data source using flux?

Tags: influxdb, flux

I have the following source table:

```
Table1
time  | sensor
2     | 1.0
5     | 2.0
7     | 4.0
```

and secondary source

```
Table2
time  | temperature
1     | 20.0
10    | 30.0
```

Times are in nanosecond precision which I would like to retain.
What I would like to have in resulting table is exactly same time series as in Table1 and additionally interpolated values of temperature from Table2.

```
Table Result
time  | data | temperature
2     | 1.0  | x 
5     | 2.0  | x
7     | 4.0  | x
```

I've checked `interpolate.linear`, which unfortunately using fixed intervals. Also checked `fill` function, which doesn't interpolate.

How to join two tables with interpolation?

Comment: Struggling with the exact same issue.